# Can I write the results of a DB query line by line and skip the data frame in Python 3?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, csv

tl;dr: I'm looking for a memory efficient method to write 22MM records to a pipe delimited csv.

I'm pulling 22MM records to a database using pyodbc and pandas. I'm running into a memory issue with my data frame. It chokes on so many records. I know there is the file stream method, but I've only used it for combining CSVs, not writing database query results. Can I somehow stream the query to disk without first hitting RAM?

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as db
import time
import os

print("Connecting to SQL Server database" + time.strftime(' %H:%M:%S'))
connection_string = 'DSN=foo;'
conn = db.connect(connection_string)
print("Querying Database" + time.strftime(' %H:%M:%S'))
csr = conn.cursor()
sql = 'SELECT * FROM table'
df = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
conn.commit()
csr.close()
conn.close()
#Write File
print('Writing results.csv'+ time.strftime(' %H:%M:%S'))
df.to_csv(os.path.join(pathvar, '_results.csv'), sep="|",index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM table'
csr.execute(sql)
for row in csr:
    // Write the row to a file
```

Comment: It will take several hours before I can test this. Thanks!